# How can I combine multiple photos into a single image on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, image-editing

I want to combine multiple photos like this

[image]
I tried  many apps like diptic, picstich and many more.

But they all combine like this.

[image]

Just a bit of clarification: I don't want to create panorama, don't want to stitch and mix images. I just want to add multiple images horizontally or vertically.

Comment: I don't want to create panorama, don't want to stitch and mix images. I just want to add multiple images horizontally or vertically

Comment: Great question - it's clear you want to stack the images as if more than one iOS device were showing both images full size - all the apps like Keynote that do this seem to enforce rigid canvas sizes and not allow you to stitch images in multiples of the basic image size.

Comment: Its a really good question, as a work around you will need to edit these on a desktop environment.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [Frame Magic](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id457447080). There's a free version and a 99¢ version